# Converting UTC time in local time in PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: postgresql

I run a Postgres 8.3 database where times seem to be stored in UTC without time zone.
I am trying to display in local time but not with '+01' suffix :

With select scheduled_start_ts I get :
2014-01-20 05:01:35.663

With select scheduled_start_ts at time zone 'MET' :
2014-01-20 05:01:35.663+01

I would like to get "2014-01-20 06:01:35.663" which is in local time.

The database I am using cannot be modified and I am not allowed to modify how data are stored.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but Postgres is quite outdated and no longer supported. You should really plan an upgrade to a 9.x version.

Comment: You're right but I am only a user of this database provided with its application. I can just query, not writing nor upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format times, use the `to_char` function. See [formatting  functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) in the docs.

```
regress=> SELECT to_char( 
   (TIMESTAMP '2014-01-20 05:01:35.663' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') 
   AT TIME ZONE 'MET',
   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
   );

       to_char       
---------------------
 2014-01-20 06:01:35
(1 row)
```

The `(TIMESTAMP 'xxx' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')` gets me a `timestamptz` with the correct time, by *re-interpreting* the `TIMESTAMP` as being in UTC. The second `AT TIME STAMP` instead *converts* the timestamptz into a `timestamp` in timezone `MET`. This then gets formatted.

Whatever the SQL standards committe were smoking when they designed this, I never, ever, ever want to be anywhere near it.

Comment: @Bruno Glad to hear it. Please consider accepting the answer (tick, top left) to save others time.